# Increment the value of () by 1,

Tags: java, variables, instance

Looking for some pointers in this code below,

I am needing to add code to the constructor to set the `number` instance variable of a newly created `Entrant` object to the value of the class variable `nextNumber` and then increment the value of `nextNumber` by 1, ready for the next `Entrant` object to be created.

```
{ private static int nextNumber = 1;

/* instance variables */

   private int number;       // entrant's number
   private String name;      // entrant's name
   private String category;  // "E1", "E2" or "E3"
   private double time;
   /**
        * Constructor for objects of class Entrant.
        */
       public Entrant()
       {
          super();
          this.name = "";
          this.category = "";
          this.time = 0.0;

          }
}
```

Am I write to say I need to add `this.number = nextNumber`
The add an If statement with the increment.?

This is my first post so be gentle lol
Thanks for any pointers in the right directions

Thanks

Comment: Sorry? Im not sure what you mean

Comment: In the consructor, set the number to the current nextnumber and then increment nextNumber by 1.

Comment: Thanks for that, Am I on the right track ? number = nextNumber  myNumber++; tA

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question.
You can use `this.number = nextNumber` and then `nextNumber++`, but you have to be careful: you're not controlling the order of access to variable `nextNumber`. From your question I cannot say if this could be an issue.